# Interpretation of Clark-Evans test and Hopkins-Skellam test (complete spatial randomness)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, spatial, randomness

When I’am calculating a Clark Evans or Hopkins-Skellam test to test for complete spatial randomness a value with R/A < 1 signifies a clustered point pattern; R/A = 1 would be a random point pattern.

Does R/A = 0.9 mean my point pattern is close to complete spatial randomness or is this an incorrect interpretation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a value of 0.9 means that your pattern is "closer" to CSR than a pattern with a value of e.g. 0.1, which typically would be very clustered. You would have to make a hypothesis test to say whether the clustering is significant.

Note: Clark-Evans is a crude index and there are many other ways to detect clustering (e.g. based on functional summary statistics) which you could also try out.